# Foreign language Chatterbot web app

Tags: python, web-applications, artificial-intelligence, chatbot

My goal is to write some sort of chatterbot that speaks in spanish. I've seen examples for simple python chatterbots, but their answers are mostly just random. I want the bot to partially understand the question and formulate a response to it, like http://cleverbot.com does. I'm guessing I would want to use python for this since I want it to be a web app. What's involved in making something like this? Are there any libraries that do this already?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a starting place, I'd take a look at the Natural Language Toolkit: http://www.nltk.org/.

Comment: Thanks! Researching this led me to pyaiml which seems to be what I want. NLTK looks like it's much to powerful for me needs, and kind of beyond my limited understanding of python.

Answer (score 0):

Spanish chatterbots are listed on:
http://www.chatbots.org/language/spanish/

There is a forum for beginners 'New to chatbot programming'
http://www.chatbots.org/ai_zone/viewforum/35/

And a document with the very first guidelines:
/ai_zone/viewthread/492/

And a support forum for a recent launched tool to build a chatbot your self, called ChatScript:
/ai_zone/viewforum/44/

As I new member, I'm only allowed to leave 2 hyperlinks, which I understand, but you probably know how to extend to the full URL :-)